# Show double as percentage without decimals with ToString method

Tags: c#, tostring

Looking for:

```
95,4545454545455 -> 95 %
```

I tried using:

```
String resultAsPercentage = result.ToString("##0 %");
```

But, it shows

```
9545 %
```

Then, I solved my problem using *regex*:

[image]

Question: Why my `ToString` method hasn't worked? And how to fix it to avoid using regex?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: @TimSchmelter. No, just show the integer part.

Comment: Thank you all guys, really nice ways of solving my problem :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As documented on [Custom Numeric Format Strings](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0c899ak8(v=vs.110).aspx#SpecifierPct), the `%` modifier multiplies the value by 100 before inserting the `%`. It's intended to be used with fractions. To disable this special meaning of `%`, [escape it by preceding it with `@"\"`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0c899ak8(v=vs.110).aspx#SpecifierEscape).

Alternatively, you could take the `%` out of the format string, and append it manually: `result.ToString("##0") + " %"`.

Comment: `result.ToString(@"##0 \%")` worked for me.. Many thanks :)

Comment: It will only work if you wish a 4/5 rounding, and that is not what you wrote.

Comment: @Gustav Ah, I see the OP's comment now, "No, just show the integer part". Yeah, that doesn't match the OP's code nor my answer. If the OP wishes to truncate, then Shadow's answer should be used.

Answer (score 3):

One way can be [`Clone`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.cultureinfo.clone.aspx) a culture (like [`InvariantCulture`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.cultureinfo.invariantculture.aspx)), set it's [`PercentPositivePattern`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.numberformatinfo.percentpositivepattern.aspx) to `0`, divide your value by `100` and get it's string representation using [The percent (`"P"`) format specifier](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dwhawy9k%28v=vs.110%29.aspx#PFormatString) with `0` precision and *that* cloned culture as;

```
var clone = (CultureInfo)CultureInfo.InvariantCulture.Clone();
clone.NumberFormat.PercentNegativePattern = 0;
Console.WriteLine(((int)95.4545454545455 / 100.0).ToString("P0", clone)); // 95 %
```

You can see all associated patterns on [Remarks section](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.numberformatinfo.percentpositivepattern.aspx#Anchor_2) on that page.

[image]

You can guaranteed to set [`PercentNegativePattern` property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.numberformatinfo.percentnegativepattern.aspx) as well for negative values.

Comment: This is neat, except that it performs a 4/5 rounding which doesn't correlate with _.., just show the integer part._

Comment: @Gustav Sorry but I didn't understand your comment clearly. What do you mean by _4/5 rounding_ and _doesn't correlate with .._ exactly?

Comment: I mean, that your expression will return 96 % for 95.545454545 where - to me - _just show the integer part_ means 95 %.

Comment: @Gustav Oh, I see now. You are completely right. `545454545` will rounds up. I change my code as `(int)95.4545454545455 / 100.0`. Casting `int` first and then divide it to `100.0` can solve my problem in my humble opinion.

Answer (score 3):

You can use thew [`P`(ercentage) format specifier](https://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/dwhawy9k(v=vs.95).aspx#PFormatString), you need to divide through 100 because the specifier multiplies it by 100:

```
decimal value = 95.4545454545455m;
String resultAsPercentage = (value / 100).ToString("P0");  // 95%
```

If you need the space between the value and the percentage symbol you *could* use this approach:

```
NumberFormatInfo nfi = (NumberFormatInfo)NumberFormatInfo.CurrentInfo.Clone();
nfi.PercentSymbol = " %";
String resultAsPercentage = (value / 100).ToString("P0", nfi);  // 95 %
```

Comment: Tim, I think OP needs `95 %` not `%95` or `95%`. You need to change current culture's `PercentPositivePattern` property to `0` if it's not by default.

Comment: @SonerGönül: you're right and probably this approach is too cumbersome , i've edited it to support it anyway.

Answer (score 3):

If you don't care about rounding, you can use the following:

```
double result = 95.4545454545;
String resultAsPercentage = (int)result + " %";
System.out.println(resultAsPercentage);
```

Output is: `95 %`

Casting to an int drops the decimal places without rounding